# AWS Glue crawler for Athena query is not showing all the records that i have in S3 bucket

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis

I have a C# application that logs audit records to Kinesis Firehose so those get PUT into a S3 bucket. That is working perfectly because I can see the files in the S3 bucket.

I'm using a Dynamic Partition for 2 fields `Entity` and `EntityName` (those are part of my JSON structure) because I read that doing this will help to reduce costs on Athena query and also faster results.

Then I setup an AWS Glue Crawler pointing to the same location s3 bucket.  When I first ran the crawler I got data and then I query it with Athena:

```
SELECT * FROM data
```

Here you can see the 9 records I got and also you can see the data schema

[image]

Then I made some other changes in my C# application to get more logs and I could see the files added to my bucket. Then I ran the crawler again but the Athena query is still showing the same 9 records.

Seems that the crawler for some reason is not finding or updating the data.

Any clue?

Comment: If your new files are being placed on new partitions you will need to re-run crawler or repair table using MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name> to add these new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the crawler.

1. Go to crawlers in AWS Glue.
2. Click in the crawler name your are interested in.
3. Click in Run Crawler.
4. If you want to run the crawler with a frequency time, go to Schedule.